# Getting an error while executing a Hive Query which involves a Subquery in the FROM Clause

Tags: hive, subquery, hiveql

I have a table with the schema as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (`membertype` varchar(1));

INSERT INTO Table1 (`membertype`)
VALUES
    ('Y'),('H'),('U'),('W'),('W'),('W'),('H'),('H'),('U'),
    ('U'),('P'),('P'),(''),('P'),('P'),('P'),(''),('W'),
    ('Y'),('Y'),('Y'),('H'),('D'),('D'),('D'),('D'),('H'),
    ('W'),('W');
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the count of each type in the column and also their percentage to the total number of types in the column.

I tested the below query in MYSQL and got the desired result:

```
select (case when m.membertype='Y' then 'Young Adult' 
    when m.membertype='H' then 'Head' 
    when m.membertype='W' then 'Spouse' 
    when m.membertype='P' then 'Aged Parent' 
    when m.membertype='U' then 'Unknown' 
    when m.membertype='D' then 'Deceased' else 'No Match' end) as type,
    count(*) as typecount,
    count(*)/t.total*100 as percentage from Table1 as m,
    (select count(*) as total from Table1) as t group by membertype;

type       typecount    percentage
No Match      2          6.8966
Deceased      4          13.7931
Head          5          17.2414
Aged Parent   5          17.2414
Unknown       3          10.3448
Spouse        6          20.6897
Young Adult   4          13.7931
```

**

[Link](http://sqlfiddle.com#!9/377d0/2)

**

The same query fails in HIVE with the below error:

```
select (case when h.member='Y' then 'Young Adult' 
when h.member='H' then 'Head' 
when h.member='W' then 'Spouse' 
when h.member='P' then 'Aged Parent' 
when h.member='U' then 'Unknown' 
when h.member='D' then 'Deceased' else 'No Match' end) as type,
count(*) as typecount,
count(*)/t.total*100 as percentage from hhinfo as h,
(select count(*) as total from hhinfo) as t group by member;


FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:277 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'total'
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly add `total` to the `group by` clause? `...as t group by member, total`

Comment: How silly of me.. That did the trick. Thank you very much @JaimeCr :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explicitly add `total` to the `group by clause`

`...as t group by member, total`

Comment: Thanks again Buddy :)